# How do I transfer a git repo to my other computer?

Tags: git, github

I've got a git repo set up on my iMac and I'd like to download it to my MacBook so I can work on it there. How do I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can `git clone` it like any git repository. If you have git-daemon setup, it's:

```
git clone git://your-imac/repoName
```

If not, you can use ssh:

```
git clone username@your-imac:/path/to/your/repo
```

Comment: The second part of this will be getting your work from the macbook back to the imac. That would be `git remote add macbook username@macbook:/path/to/repo` and then `fetch`, `merge` etc.

Answer (score 0):

If it's accessible just use:

```
git clone
```

Otherwise just copy the .git folder by hand. That should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Git is self-contained - simply copying the contents of the repository would work fine.

If you have SSH access to the machine it's currently on, you could also simply use `git clone`.

Comment: I would clone before copying, because issues can arise if the source git version is newer than the destination git version.

Comment: When I tried copying the files over git was complaining about bad file signatures and so on, so it doesn't appear to be a reliable solution.

Answer (score 0):

In Mac machine:
Goto required folder using terminal.

1. Open terminal
2. type **cd** and drag and drop folder on terminal.
3. you are in same folder where you want to download
4. use command:

   ```
   cd <folder path of local machine>
   git clone <url> 

   eg: Mac-mini: macuser$ cd /Users/macuser/Desktop/GIT_PROJ
   Mac-mini:GIT_PROJ macuser$  git clone https://abcd@bitbucket.org/abcd/sample.git
   ```
5. it will download the Repository to you local machine.